# clearing all textInput field on submit react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, react-native

i want to clear the all text input field on the button press instead it throws a an error saying undefined is not an option, as trying to take value={this.state.inputTextValue} from   and clearing the input setState({inputTextValue : ''})

```
const[username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const[mobile, setMobile] = useState("");
  
  const[ isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const order = async () => {
      axios
      .post(
        "*****************",
        JSON.stringify({
          username:username,
          mobile: mobile,
        })
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setIsSubmit(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    };

    if (isSubmit) order();
  }, [isSubmit]);

   const orderHandler = (text) => {
       setUsername(text);     
  };
```

**HERE CLEARING THE TEXTINPUT VALUE ONPRESS**

```
   const handleSubmitEdit = () => {
     
    setState({inputTextValue : ''})
  };
  

 return (
         <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
              >
          
                  <View style={styles.formwrap}>
                  
                  <Form style={styles.mainform}>
                  <View style={styles.formgroup}> 
              <SafeAreaView>


                      <View style={styles.formItems}>
```

**HERE TAKING VALUE={value={this.state.inputTextValue}}**

```
                        <TextInput placeholder="Full Name"
                        onChangeText={orderHandler}
                        value={this.state.inputTextValue}
                        />
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.formItems}>
                        <TextInput  placeholder="Mobile" 
                        style={styles.input}
                        keyboardType={"phone-pad"}
                        onChangeText={(text) => setMobile(text)}
                        value={this.state.inputTextValue}
                        />
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.submit}
                        onPress={() => {setIsSubmit(true),handleSubmitEdit()}}'>
                        <Text style={[styles.submitText]}>ORDER</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>                              
                  </View>
                  </SafeAreaView>                                            
                 </View>     
                  </Form>                      
                  </View>    
           </ScrollView>   
 )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error your getting ? You should now since React 16 use functional components. For management you I think it’s a wiser to read a ternanary operator. You should use the SETTING with USESTATE operator state when using the state operator. Remember, props only get rendered on state change and props change.

Const [foo, setFoo] = useState(‘’)

useEffect(() => {
try{

const order = async () => {
const data = await axios
.post(
"*****************",
JSON.stringify({
username:foo
})
[]      )

```
};
```

}catch(err){

Console.log(err)

}

Comment: Actullay i want to clear the textinput field after pressing submit buttonmrest everything works fine